# PHP $_POST returns an empty array for http://localhost on MAMP server

Tags: php, http-post, httprequest, mamp

I am very new to the world of PHH and I am trying to implement some Rest API.

I have installed a MAMP server on my MAC. Then I wrote the following php code in api.php:

```
<?php
$api = new RestUtils;
$api->processRequest();

class RestUtils
{
public static function processRequest()
{
       $request_method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
       var_dump($request_method);
       var_dump($_POST);
       var_dump($_REQUESTS);
    }
 }
?>
```

Then in my terminal window, I execute the following:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "john"}' http://localhost:8888/api.php
```

I get the following output:

string(4) "post"

array(0){
}

array(0){
}

When I call call

```
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
```

it returns {"name":"john"}

Answer (score 0):

You're posting a raw string. If you're expecting to PHP to process that string into $_POST, you have to submit it as a `key=value` pair, e.g.

```
-d 'foo:{"name":"john"}'
```

and then

```
echo $_POST['foo'];
```

Comment: I get still nothing. The array is still empty.